# fnmatch pattern matching

Tags: c

I'm trying to match a pattern and this keeps failing (return 1):

```
fnmatch(findme, d_name, FNM_PATHNAME)
```

when findme= "cproject", d_name="./.cproject"  Also in gdb debugger I tried this:

```
//in gdb
p fnmatch("f","fa",0x10)
```

returns 1.  If match "f" and "f" it returns 0 (match).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

f only matches f. You need f* to match fa.

Comment: To use multiple flags, How to set multiple flags in 3rd argument? Like `FNM_FILE_NAME | FNM_PERIOD` or `FNM_FILE_NAME & FNM_PERIOD`